# Configurable map viewer cannot display non-cached basemap?

Tags: basemap, dojo, configurable-map-viewer

I download the sample from [github](https://github.com/cmv/cmv-app). Then I tried to add a custom basemap at the mapOption section. I have followed the instruction given in [here](https://docs.cmv.io/en/latest/configure/mapOptions/). Also, I followed [this post](https://github.com/cmv/cmv-app/issues/84) as well. But none worked, no map comes out. I only see empty map grid with "esri" logo at the bottom right corner. What have I done wrong ? How can I show a custom (non-cached) basemap in the mapOptions section.

---

**Update :** 
I find out that if i use cached basemap (like http://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Terrain_Base/MapServer), it works. I have no luck with non-cached basemap. Then I tried to an older version (1.3.4) too. And its exactly the same, it woks only on a cached basemap.

Here is what I have done using non-cached map service:

1. Edit viewer.js to add the "Define" keyword and add "mapOptions"

> ```
> define([  ... 'esri/geometry/Point', 'esri/dijit/Basemap',
> 'esri/dijit/BasemapLayer' ],
> ```

---

> ```
> function (units, Extent, esriConfig, /*urlUtils,*/ GeometryService,
> ImageParameters,GoogleMapsLoader,i18n, topic, has, Point, Basemap, 
> BasemapLayer)
> ```

---

> ```
>     mapOptions:{
>         // tiled layer
>         basemap: **new Basemap({
>             id: 'soco',
>             layers: [new BasemapLayer({
>                 url: 'http://gis-webpub.sonoma-county.org/arcgis/rest/services/BaseMap/SonomaCountyBaseMap/MapServer/'
>             })]
>         }),
>         center: new Point({
>             x: 6356023.515330248,
>             y: 1917313.443425702,
>             spatialReference: {
>                 wkid: 102642
>             }
>         }),
>         zoom: 5
>     }**,
> ```

Am I missing something ?

Comment: This question seems to be about Beta software: https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/q/909/115

Comment: In that case I think you should [edit] your question to focus it on the earlier version.

Comment: Please do not comment on you own question. Instead, [Edit] the question to integrate the ne information.

Comment: allright vince. i update my post.